# Checking for amount of open files while running SystemVerilog testbench

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, test-bench, synopsys-vcs

I am running a test to compare output data of the system to a set of golden data generated on a text file, but when the test runs to around 2000 frames +, I start getting an error where is says:

```
warning-Cannot open file
 file could not be opened. Too many open files.
```

I tried to look for a system task in SystemVerilog to see if there is a task that can show all currently open files while the test is running, but I can't seem to find one. Is there a way for this to be done?

Comment: Most likely, you hit an operating system limit on opened file descriptors. It has nothing to do with verilog.

Comment: I know that there is a limit to how many opened file descriptors are available, but because I always use $fclose after I am done with the data file for each frame, I would assume that the test can just reuse the value for another file when I call for $fopen again, is this not the case?

Comment: Yes I did, and I have used the integer values returned to confirm that there is some code opening files in between every frame that is not mine because the integer identifier is jumping by 2 instead of 1. 
But since I am not the only one working on the project, its kind of hard to find out which bit of code is opening files, hence i was trying to figure if a function as described in the question exists, if not i guess I just have to do it the hard way to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the IEEE Std 1800-2017 offers any way to directly know how many files are currently open.

However, you could look at the integer value returned by `$fopen` to see the value of the last file descriptor which was opened.  When I open many files, the value increments by one every time a new file is opened.  I tried this on 2 simulators.

Keep in mind that there are 2 ways to call `$fopen`: multichannel descriptor and file descriptor.  They return different values.

Perhaps your simulator has a proprietary way to check for the number of open files.  Look through your documentation, or contact the vendor for support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in SystemVerilog. However, you can use /proc file system on Linux to get a list of all open files for a process (use simv pid here):

```
ls -la /proc/<pid>/fd
```

If you need to do this in simv, you would need to write a small DPI-function and do the above using getpid() and system() C-functions.

Please see also:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333186/how-to-list-the-open-file-descriptors-and-the-files-they-refer-to-in-my-curren